# block specific app capabilities in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx):

> Windows Store apps that need programmatic access to user resources such as the Pictures library or connected devices such as a webcam, must declare the appropriate capability.

Is there a way to programatically identify when an app is asking for a specific capability, and to allow/deny the request?

I would prefer c# solutions, but also any other way will be ok.

Comment: What do you mean by programatically? Do what to scan app files to see what does it want? Each app have an xml file that contains those information.

Comment: scanning that xml file will be great!where is it located? even if I find this xml - how can I block the application from being installed?

Comment: you don't have control over whether an app can be installed - the user does.  If an app uses the webcam it declared that (or won't execute or get into store) and exposes that to the user via the Store download page.

Comment: Have you had a look at AppLocker yet? It's exact features for Windows 8 don't seem to be advertised that much but maybe a sales person at Microsoft could find out... ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to programatically identify when an app is asking for a specific capability, and to allow/deny the request?

You don't. Windows handles this (with user input as apropos). AppLocker is the Windows feature if you want to block certain packages from installing.